# Is it possible to get values from an HTML table using Behat/Mink

Tags: php, html, testing, behat, mink

I am starting to use Behat/Mink with the Selenium2 driver and I wondered if it was possible to get the value from a particular cell of a HTML table that might be on my page. The td tags do not have anything to identify them. But I used to use actiwate unit tests and they used to have a function that allowed me to get a cell based on its position. Does anything like that exist?.

I would even take an answer that gave me an entire row at this stage!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

```
/**
 * @Given /^The cell contains "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function cellContains($value)
{
    $td = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css',
        sprintf('table tbody tr td:contains("%s")', $value)
    );

    // rest of your code
}
```

If you could provide an example of the table maybe I can give you a more accurate code.